# return array from function by passing string

Tags: php, arrays

i have following function where i have brands info in an array. i should get array containing those info when i pass brand name to this function.

```
function brand_info($brand)
{
    $brands_list=array ( 
    'lg'=>
    array(
    'name'           => 'LG Phone Company',
    'country'        =>  'country',
    'founded_year'   =>  '2001'
    ),
    'nokia'=>
    array(
    'name'           => 'Nokia Phone Company',
    'country'        =>  'country',
    'founded_year'   =>  '2001'
    )
    );


    if(in_array($brand,$brands_list))
    {
        // return array containg company info
    }
}
```

this should return an array by which i can show these info.

```
$brand_info=brand_info($brand_name);
echo $brand_info['name'];
```

what may be the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean `return $brands_list[$brand];`? Apparently you already know how to work with arrays, so what is the problem?

Comment: @felix yes exactly, but its returning Null, i don't know what i am missing

Comment: Well, if the brand is not in the array, it does not return anything...

Comment: @FelixKling i am passing 'nokia' to this function. you can see array contain 'nokia', but its not returning array.

Comment: Ah, `in_array` tests whether the *value* exists in the array. You are testing for a *key*, so it should be `if(isset($brands_list[$brand]))`.

Comment: thanks @FelixKling . i was missing one thing. but everything is working now. thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're passing in the brandname then this would suffice:

```
function brand_info($brand)
{
    $brands_list=array ( 
    'lg'=>
    array(
    'name'           => 'LG Phone Company',
    'country'        =>  'country',
    'founded_year'   =>  '2001'
    ),
    'Nokia'=>
    array(
    'name'           => 'Nokia Phone Company',
    'country'        =>  'country',
    'founded_year'   =>  '2001'
    )
    );

    if (array_key_exists($brand,$brands_list)) {
      return $brands_list[$brand];
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}

$brandinfo = brand_info('Nokia');
echo $brandinfo['name']; // will print "Nokia Phone Company"
```

Comment: but its returning Null, i used var_dump($brandinfo); to show.

Comment: The above returns correctly for me, and it's not using anything that would depend on your PHP config, so it should be working for you.

Comment: Make sure you've typed all variables correctly @NaeemX2. This code is valid.

Comment: you are right... i am missing. its working now. thanks for your help.

Comment: You may have problems if you do not test weather the array key exists.

Comment: @edelgado true, but thats simple enough to change - see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

May seem trivial but...

```
return $brands_list[$brand]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function brand_info($brand)
{
    $brands_list=array ( 
    'lg'=>
    array(
    'name'           => 'LG Phone Company',
    'country'        =>  'country',
    'founded_year'   =>  '2001'
    ),
    'nokia'=>
    array(
    'name'           => 'Nokia Phone Company',
    'country'        =>  'country',
    'founded_year'   =>  '2001'
    )
    );


    if(in_array($brand,$brands_list))
    {
        return $brand_list[$brand];
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then

```
$info = brand_info($my_brand);
if(!is_null($info)){ echo $info['name']; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function brand_info($brand) {
    $brands_list=array (
        'lg'=>
            array(
                    'name'           => 'LG Phone Company',
                    'country'        =>  'country',
                    'founded_year'   =>  '2001'
            ),
        'Nokia'=>
            array(
                    'name'           => 'Nokia Phone Company',
                    'country'        =>  'country',
                    'founded_year'   =>  '2001'
            )
    );


    foreach ($brands_list as $brandname=>$info) {
        if($brandname==$brand) {
            return $info;
        }
    }
    return array();
}
```